# Table editing with excel vba causing crashing and cell lockup

Tags: vba, excel, crash, lockup

I have made a userform that allows the user to select a table and add rows to it and fill those rows with various information, all from the userform. I have run into a few problems with this.

First after adding or during adding the items (after hitting submit) excel would crash. It occurs randomly and is hard to reproduce.

**Second after running the macro there is a good chance that all the cells in the workbook and every other object except the userform button will stop working, meaning you can't edit interact or even select anything. Then when I close the workbook excel crashes after saving. This is my major offender and I think causes the other problem.**

What causes this freezing and why does it occur? How do I fix it? I have looked around and haven't found anything circumstantial. One post said that I should try editing the table with no formatting on it and I did that and it didn't work.

I can provide the excel workbook at a request basis via pm.

[image: Problem Userform]

The code:

On Activate -

```
Public Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Set cBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set dsheet = cBook.Sheets("DATA")

End Sub
```

Help Checkbox -

```
Private Sub cbHelp_Click()

If Me.cbHelp.Value = True Then

    Me.lbHelp.Visible = True

Else

    Me.lbHelp.Visible = False

End If

End Sub
```

Brand combobox -

```
Public Sub cmbBrand_Change()

brandTableName = cmbBrand.Value
brandTableName = CleanBrandTableName(brandTableName)

'if brand_edit is not = to a table name then error is thrown
On Error Resume Next

If Err = 380 Then
    Exit Sub
Else

cmbItemID.RowSource = brandTableName

End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Set cmbItemID's text to nothing after changing to a new brand

cmbItemID.Text = ""


End Sub
```

CleanBrandTableName(brandTableName) function -

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CleanBrandTableName(ByVal brandTableName As String) As String

Dim s As Integer
Dim cleanResult As String

For s = 1 To Len(brandTableName)
    Select Case Asc(Mid(brandTableName, s, 1))
        Case 32, 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122:
            cleanResult = cleanResult & Mid(brandTableName, s, 1)
        Case 95
            cleanResult = cleanResult & " "
        Case 38
            cleanResult = cleanResult & "and"
    End Select
Next s
CleanBrandTableName = Replace(WorksheetFunction.Trim(cleanResult), " ", "_")

End Function

Public Function CleanSpecHyperlink(ByVal specLink As String) As String

Dim cleanLink As Variant

cleanLink = specLink

cleanLink = Replace(cleanLink, "=HYPERLINK(", "")
cleanLink = Replace(cleanLink, ")", "")
cleanLink = Replace(cleanLink, ",", "")
cleanLink = Replace(cleanLink, """", "")
cleanLink = Replace(cleanLink, "Specs", "")

CleanSpecHyperlink = cleanLink

End Function
```

Browse button -

```
Public Sub cbBrowse_Click()

Dim rPos As Long
Dim lPos As Long
Dim dPos As Long

    specLinkFileName = bFile
    rPos = InStrRev(specLinkFileName, "\PDFS\")
    lPos = Len(specLinkFileName)
    dPos = lPos - rPos
    specLinkFileName = Right(specLinkFileName, dPos)
    Me.tbSpecLink.Text = specLinkFileName

End Sub
```

bFile function -

```
Option Explicit

Public Function bFile() As String

bFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose a file to open")

If bFile = "" Then

    MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"

    Exit Function

End If

End Function
```

Preview button -

```
Private Sub cbSpecs_Click()

If specLinkFileName = "" Then Exit Sub

cBook.FollowHyperlink (specLinkFileName)

End Sub
```

Add Item button -

```
Private Sub cbAddItem_Click()

Dim brand As String
Dim description As String
Dim listPrice As Currency
Dim cost As Currency
Dim Notes As String
Dim other As Variant

itemID = Me.tbNewItem.Text
brand = Me.tbBrandName.Text
description = Me.tbDescription.Text
specLink = Replace(specLinkFileName, specLinkFileName, "=HYPERLINK(""" & specLinkFileName & """,""Specs"")")

If Me.tbListPrice.Text = "" Then

    listPrice = 0
Else

    listPrice = Me.tbListPrice.Text

End If

If Me.tbCost.Text = "" Then

    cost = 0

Else

    cost = Me.tbCost.Text

End If

Notes = Me.tbNotes.Text
other = Me.tbOther.Text


If Me.lbItemList.listCount = 0 Then
    x = 0
End If

With Me.lbItemList
    Me.lbItemList.ColumnCount = 8

    .AddItem
    .List(x, 0) = itemID
    .List(x, 1) = brand
    .List(x, 2) = description
    .List(x, 3) = specLink
    .List(x, 4) = listPrice
    .List(x, 5) = cost
    .List(x, 6) = Notes
    .List(x, 7) = other

    x = x + 1

End With

End Sub
```

Submit button -

```
Private Sub cbSubmit_Click()

Dim n As Long
Dim v As Long
Dim vTable() As Variant
Dim r As Long
Dim o As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim w As Variant

Set brandTable = dsheet.ListObjects(brandTableName)

o = 1

listAmount = lbItemList.listCount

    v = brandTable.ListRows.Count

    w = 0

    For c = 1 To listAmount

        If brandTable.ListRows(v).Range(, 1).Value <> "" Then

        brandTable.ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True
        brandTable.ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True

        Else

        brandTable.ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True
        End If

    Next

    ReDim vTable(1000, 1 To 10)

    For n = 0 To listAmount - 1

        vTable(n + 1, 1) = lbItemList.List(n, 0)
        vTable(n + 1, 2) = lbItemList.List(n, 1)
        vTable(n + 1, 3) = lbItemList.List(n, 2)
        vTable(n + 1, 5) = lbItemList.List(n, 4)
        vTable(n + 1, 6) = lbItemList.List(n, 5)
        vTable(n + 1, 7) = lbItemList.List(n, 6)
        vTable(n + 1, 8) = lbItemList.List(n, 7)

        If lbItemList.List(n, 3) = "" Then

        ElseIf lbItemList.List(n, 3) <> "" Then

            vTable(n + 1, 4) = lbItemList.List(n, 3)

        End If

        If n = 0 And brandTable.DataBodyRange(1, 1) <> "" Then

        For r = 1 To brandTable.ListRows.Count
            If brandTable.DataBodyRange(r, 1) <> "" Then
                o = r + 1
'                brandTable.ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True
            End If
        Next
        End If

        brandTable.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange(n + o).Value = vTable(n + 1, 1)
        brandTable.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange(n + o).Value = vTable(n + 1, 2)
        brandTable.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange(n + o).Value = vTable(n + 1, 3)
        brandTable.ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange(n + o).Value = vTable(n + 1, 4)
        brandTable.ListColumns(5).DataBodyRange(n + o).Value = vTable(n + 1, 5)
        brandTable.ListColumns(6).DataBodyRange(n + o).Value = vTable(n + 1, 6)
        brandTable.ListColumns(7).DataBodyRange(n + o).Value = vTable(n + 1, 7)
        brandTable.ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange(n + o).Value = vTable(n + 1, 8)


    Next

    brandTable.DataBodyRange.Select

        Selection.Font.Bold = True
        Selection.WrapText = True

    brandTable.ListColumns(5).DataBodyRange.Select

        Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"

    brandTable.ListColumns(6).DataBodyRange.Select

        Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Remove Items button -

```
Private Sub cbRemoveItems_Click()

Dim intCount As Long

For intCount = lbItemList.listCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
     If lbItemList.Selected(intCount) Then
        lbItemList.RemoveItem (intCount)
        x = x - 1
     End If
Next intCount


End Sub
```

There is other code that does things for the other tabs but they don't interact with this tabs code.

Comment: If you can send it to tommy70458@gmail.com I'll look at it.

Comment: I sent the email. I don't know if you got it.

Comment: Perfect timing.  I'll take a look now.

Comment: The best way to reproduce the bug is to go to the data sheet double click the add items button, then select the last brand table (electraled) and add items to it (I just use test and 10 and 5 for the list and cost prices.